# Arrange multiple images (dynamically created) properly in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-videoview

I have created an image and a video gallery where I'm retrieving images and videos saved at server side and displaying them in a `LinearLayout`.

I'm creating `ImageView`, `VideoView`, `LinearLayout` & `ScrollView` dynamically based on number of Images/Videos.

**Code snippet:**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            Log.e("onPost", "..");
            int i;

            for(i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                img = new ImageView(Image.this);
                img.setImageBitmap(list.get(i));
                img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                img.computeScroll();
                img.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                img.getLayoutParams().width=500;
                img.getLayoutParams().height=300;
                picLL.addView(img);
            }
            sv.addView(picLL);
            sv.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            setContentView(sv);
            dialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
```

This code displays all images one after another like this:

[image: 1]

Same with videos.

But it doesn't look good.I want them to be arranged as in gallery.like this:

[image]

How could I achieve this.

Any kind of suggestions would be of great help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use grid view with GridLayoutManager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: Now am on this [tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android)

Comment: could you please suggest me any tutorial which will help in adding bitmap or url in gridview @r7v